# Is there a way to create Azure DevOps Pull Request Status links that open in a new tab?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to have status policies open their link in a new tab? Like when setting the attribute `target="_blank"` on an `<a>` tag.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

[image]

Comment: You reference the REST API for the links - are you trying to reference those from some other UI, or are you trying to get the Azure DevOps UI (as above) to open things in a new tab)?

Comment: Azure DevOps UI to open my custom Pull Requests statuses in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have status policies open their link in a new tab

I am afraid this is impossible.

PR check status page is designed to be shown as a Modal box. And there is no option available to change this behavior. It is impossible to change the source code which controls how the check status should be displayed.

Update: To Open the Status link in a new Tab

You can **Right Click** on the link and choose to `Open Link in New Tab`.

[image]

Comment: I see that the Checks are a modal box but I was wondering about the actual links when clicking through.

For example, if I were to click 'Precheckin Debug' I would like to open a new tab instead of going to the link in the existing tab.

Comment: @AndrewPham There is no option to configure this behavior. However, You can just **right click** on the link and choose to `Open Link in New Tab`.  See above screenshot.